# What's the name of something that blocks reflection on glass in front of a camera?

Tags: accessories, reflection

I have a Contour action camera that I sometimes use on a suction cup mount on glass to record something out a window.  (Say, the scenery outside a moving train.)  To block reflections on the window glass from light inside, I'm going to make some sort of large ring that slides onto the end of the camera.  I think I've seen these available commercially before.  What are they called?

Here's a mockup... black is a piece of rubber or plastic that I plan to make to put on the camera.  The blue is the window.

[image: Contour Camera]

I'm not sure what you would call this... it's not really a baffle.  But, what is it?

Comment: This is something like lens hood :) In practice lens hoods are used for the same purpose

Comment: I believe these are often called "skirts", but I've only made them, not bought them, so I don't know if that's an officially correct term.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you describe is usually referred to as a [lens skirt](http://www.lenskirt.com/lenskirt/) if made from cloth or a [rubber lens hood](http://www.bhphotovideo.com/c/search?ci=15293&N=4294205295&Ntt=rubber%20lens%20hood) when made from - you guessed it - rubber.